# Space between paragraphs, no space between paragraph and list

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, enumitem, parskip

I would like to set `0.5\baselineskip` space between paragraphs, but no space between paragraph and list. Setting `\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}` adds unnecessary space between paragraph and list:

[image: I don't need this space]

I tried to `\setlist{itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}` with `enumitem` package without any success.

Comment: the default `list` environment (nice picture on p.145 of the *latex companion*) separates the preceding text from the list by `\topsep + \parskip + \partopsep`, so you'll need to suppress that particular `\parskip`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton So you actually do need to cut it since it's added up anyways... That's very good insight! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain what you want with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\setlength\parskip{0pt}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{\vspace*{-\dimexpr\parskip\relax}}

 \begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{itemize}[label=\textendash,  nosep]
\item Some text to fill this part
\item Some text to fill this part
\item Some text to fill this part
\item Some text to fill this part
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good one, this is way better, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of it with a `\newenvironment` (there probably is a better solution):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\newenvironment{itemizezerosep}{\vspace{-\parskip}
                                \begin{itemize}[label={--},
                                                topsep=0pt,
                                                parsep=0pt,
                                                partopsep=0pt]
                                                }
                                {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{itemizezerosep}
\item Some text to fill this part
\item Some text to fill this part
\item Some text to fill this part
\item Some text to fill this part
\end{itemizezerosep}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Since you said you only want to remove the space before the list. If you to remove after as well, just add the `\vspace{-\parskip}` after the `\end{itemize}`.

**EDIT**

*As explained by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) on the comments below, one should use `\vspace` without `*` so that if by any chance the list is located after a pagebreak (at the top of the page) the space won't be removed and the list will be aligned properly.*

Comment: you don't want vspace* as that will not be removed at the top of a page (but the space that you are backing over will have been dropped)

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand clearly the mechanism behind. My experience was that `\vspace*` always removes the space and without `*` depends on the contents. Feel free to edit the answer and explain to us mortals... ;D

Comment: the only (documented) difference between vspace* and vspace is tthat the * form will make a space at the top of a page, but here you do not want negative space at the top of the page or your list will over-print the page head. You just want to negative space if the preceding paragraph space is there, which it will not be at a page break.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard), [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) and `enumitem` package documentation I finally figured out how to obtain this behavior with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
Изучив предложенный курс, обучающийся должен обладать следующими
навыками:

\begin{itemize}[before=\setlength\parskip{0pt}]
  \item правильно оценивать свойства стали;
  \item правильно выбирать оптимальное решение конструкций;
  \item рационально и экономно проектировать стальные конструкции.
\end{itemize}

Изучению курса металлических конструкций должно предшествовать
изучение следующих дисциплин: технология металлов и сварки;
сопротивление материалов; строительная механика; архитектура
промышленных и гражданских зданий.

\end{document}
```